# ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file

Tags: php, ssh

In order to upload a batch of files from the remote server, I use `ssh2_scp_recv()` in my php program's for loop. It works good for some point. But when there are more than 67 files in one folder, it start to have the error message as

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file

The program I use like the following:

```php
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');

$remote_dir="/remote_dir/";
$local_dir="/local_dir/";

$com ="ls $remote_dir";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $com);
stream_set_blocking($stream,true);
$cmd=fread($stream,4096);

$arr=explode("\n",$cmd);

$total_files=sizeof($arr);

for($i=0;$i<$total_files;$i++){
    $file_name=trim($arr[$i]);
    if($file_name!=''){
        $remote_file=$remote_dir.$file_name;       
        $local_file=$local_dir.$file_name;

        if(ssh2_scp_recv($connection, $remote_file,$local_file)){
            echo "File ".$file_name." was copied to $local_dir<br />";
        }
    }
}

fclose($stream);
```

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

One call to `fread()` may not be getting all the filenames. Use `stream_get_contents` to read until the end:

```
$cmd = stream_get_contents($stream);
```